# Style.backgroundColor or style.background is not performing it function

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Problem

The background colour of my div is not changing while running this code:

### Code

```js
var colors = [
    "rgb (255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb (255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb (0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb (0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb (0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb (255, 0, 255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById ("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.6%;
}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
```

## Expected

**I should be getting a  6 multi-color square instead of 6 squares filled with purple**.

[image: This is the result I am getting with my code]

[image: This is what I should be getting]

*Thanks for all!!*

Comment: `var squares = document.querySelectorAll("square");` - selector should be `.square`

Comment: I have changed var squares = document.querySelectorAll("square"); to var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square"); the result is still the same thing. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't work because there is space after rgb

Your code: `rgb (255,0,0)`

It should be like this,

```
var colors = [
        "rgb(255,0,0)",
        "rgb(255,255,0)",
        "rgb(0,255,0)",
        "rgb(0,255,255)",
        "rgb(0,0,255)",
        "rgb(255,0,255)"
    ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I am very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Just remove space after `rgb` color and i have add `getElementsByClassName` for `square`

```js
var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]

var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById ("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){    
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.6%;
}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly